# button Image inset changing after UIButton Touch up inside.

Tags: uibutton, ibaction

The inset I am setting keeps changing after UIButton touch up inside is called.

What IBAction happens after Touch up inside? WHy would my UIButtons UIImage be changing its position?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok so. TouchUoInside is the last IBAction performed. The button insets are a nightmare to work with so just modify what you need to to get it working. I kept my context inset at 0,0,0,0 and modified my image inset so that the left inset is equal to top+bottom inset to keep the image in scale.

Images stopped moving when pressed now.

Thanks.